# Entity generator from database

Tags: jpa, code-generation

I need to generate annotation based entity from the existing database in spring.I have tried pride but the generated entity dont having annotations.How can i generate the annotations in pride based entity or can any one suggest me a good entity generator.I want to say that i also have tried spring roo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DAL4J.jar , I think it will fulfill your need. visit http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/dal4j/

Answer (score 10):

You can try Telosys Tools, an Eclipse plugin for code generation working from an existing database with customizable Velocity templates

See: http://www.telosys.org/

Eclipse Marketplace : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

For JPA generation, a set of templates is available on GitHub : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/

Answer (score 4):

Since the 2.1.0 version of Telosys Tools you can find templates for generate full application with Spring MVC, AngularJS, Spring DATA Rest for example.

The tutorials are here : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean JPA/Hibernate entities and annotations. Spring has nothing to do with it, you need some tool that supports it. E.g. check out

1. [[image]intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea):

   [generatebydatabasemappings http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/generatebydatabasemappings.png](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/generatebydatabasemappings.png)

   From: [Generating Persistence Mappings from Database Schema](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/generating-persistence-mappings-from-database-schema). See also: [feature page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jpa_hibernate.html#link5).
2. [Creating JPA entity beans from database tables](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jpa.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_jpa_bottomup.html)
3. [Object-Relational Mappings: Generating JPA Entities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/genJPAEntities.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer.I need to generate these entities by coding.I like to design a jsp page in which we can select the database using drop down box or simply entering the DB name.Then i need to generate the entities from the selected database or tables on Jsp page submission.Any idea?

Comment: @rakeshmenon: you mean you want to dynamically select **any** database and generate entities (do you mean JPA/Hibernate classes?) for it? You want to generate classes/source code at runtime? I am not following. Can you update your question and explain it more thoroughly?

Comment: Yes, actually Iam creating annotation based entity generator project. for that, if user give database details in jsp fields, my application will have to generate the entity dynamically. thank you.